# How to deploy different files in single feature for mulitple subsites?

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, feature-activation, xml, feature-receiver

I need to deploy different images into picture library for different sub sites in a single feature, I mean I have five images, I need to deploy the first two image in the site collection, third image in subsite as well as last two images in another two subsites. I am not sure is this possible.I think we can achieve this by XML  and c#. Please suggest me some best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this by XML declarative code, but use a feature event receiver to implement anything you want with C# code:
With the feature ER code, you can easily leverage the server-side API to connect to the root site of the site collection (assuming the feature is site-scoped, i.e. site collection) and any sub-site you want (the clever approach being to create those sub-sites as well when the feature is activated, so you know their URL).
If you have an `ElementFile` as part of your feature, you can get access to it when the feature is deployed, from the ER code: simply get the `properties.Definition.RootDirectory` and build the complete path of the file you want to read. Then, use the simple and well-known API calls to upload the file wherever you want in SharePoint.